# Proving the discontinuity of a function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I was given the function $$ f(x) = \frac{x^3y + y^3}{x^6 + y^2}\ for\ all\ x^2+y^2\neq0$$
$$ f(x) = 0\ for\ all\ x^2+y^2=0$$

And was told to determine if it is continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. 

So I approached this question by taking the path $y=x^3$: 
$$ \lim_{(x,x^3)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^6 + x^9}{x^6+x^6} = 1/2$$
and $y=0$:
$$ \lim_{(x,0)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3(0) + 0}{x^6+0} = 0$$
to show that the limits will be 1/2 and 0 respectively. Therefore it is not continuous. However after I calculated it [online](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/multi-var-limit-calculator/%5Clim_%7B%5Cleft(x%2C%20y%5Cright)%5Cto%5Cleft(0%2C%200%5Cright)%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B3%7Dy%2By%5E%7B3%7D%7D%7Bx%5E%7B6%7D%2By%5E%7B2%7D%7D%5Cright)?or=input), it shows that the limit is indeed 0. What was wrong with my approach?

Comment: What you did is fine.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos so it is actually not continuous?

Comment: Already the first limit is enough to show that it's discontinuous at the origin.

Comment: No, it is not.${}$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you both so much for your help!